# SQL Server Audit sys.fn_get_audit_file

Tags: sql-server, function, audit

I am just curious if there is a way to track down the **Client IP** using the **SQL Sever audit specifications**.

The `.sqlaudit file` generated doesn't seem to have that **information** when queried out using the `sys.fn_get_audit_file builtin function`. Can anyone help?

Comment: See dba site https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112921/can-sql-server-audit-be-used-to-track-hostnames-or-ip-adresses-of-the-users-perf

Comment: Could't find in sql server. However, https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-audit.aspx might have.